# How to group on labels in aggregate query to Promscale

Tags: sql, grafana, promql, promscale

I am creating SQL queries from Grafana into [Promscale](https://www.timescale.com/promscale). There are the metric and the labels. I can not get the correct way to group by some of the labels. I tried:

```sql
SELECT time_bucket('$__interval', "time") AS "time",
       AVG("value") AS "used"
  FROM "disk_used_percent"
 WHERE $__timeFilter("time") AND
       "labels" ? ('host' == '$host_pg')
 GROUP BY 1, "labels" --> 'path'
 ORDER BY 1;
```

as well as:

```sql
SELECT time_bucket('$__interval', "time") AS "time",
       AVG("value") AS "used"
  FROM "disk_used_percent"
 WHERE $__timeFilter("time") AND
       "labels" ? ('host' == '$host_pg')
 GROUP BY 1, "path_id"
 ORDER BY 1;
```

but it does not seem the grouping works as expected. What is wrong? Corresponding PromQL query would be:

```
avg(disk_used_percent{host=~"$host_prom"}) by(path))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `VAL("<label>_id")` to group on:

```sql
SELECT time_bucket('$__interval', "time") AS "time",
       VAL("path_id") AS "path",
       AVG("value") AS "used"
  FROM "disk_used_percent"
 WHERE $__timeFilter("time") AND
       "labels" ? ('host' == '$host_pg')
 GROUP BY 1, 2
 ORDER BY 1;
```

**Side note:** also avoid using the `$__timeFilter("time")` templating macro in *Grafana* because it generates the following predicate:

```sql
"time" BETWEEN 'time range begin' AND 'time range end'
```

which may be
[problematic](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29) under *certain* circumstances.